# Как разбить список на несколько отдельных подгрупп

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Дело в том что я не пойму как разбить полученный список, на отдельные категории, то есть отдельно разные виды товаров, например катушки к катушкам и т.д., что бы оно отдельно формировало списки с этими товарами, условия для json файла я не писал.

```
all_link.append(
                {
                    "tittle": item_name,
                    "url": item_url,
                    "price": item_price
                }
            )
    with  open("dflagman.json", "w", encoding="utf-8") as file:
        json.dump(all_link, file, indent=4, ensure_ascii=False)
```

Comment: Добавьте пример входных данных, и ожидаемый результат. Пока непонятно, по каким условиям должны формироваться списки

Answer (score 0):

Могу предложить циклом пройти по каждому элементу списка и каждый раз *распределять* по спискам для каждого типа эти элементы c помощью `switch(item_type)`

Comment: Здравствуйте а не могли бы Вы пример кода написать, я новичок в python, и не пойму как правильно это написать. У меня версия python 3.8.10

Comment: @Gr1m не хватает входных данных от вас. Распишите те поля списка, который затронуты в этой проблеме, распишите ваш ожидаемый результат на примере и тому подобное